# Multiple joins on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite, join

i have the following tables:

```
Technician
Tech_ID,First_Name,Last_Name

 RT_QUEUE_Delta
 Tech_ID, RT_Complete` (references a `Tech_ID` in `Technician`).
```

I need to get the data from a row in `RT_Queue_Delta` where `RT_Completed = ??` but in my output I need to have the `First_Name` and `Last_nam`e that correlates with `Tech_id` and `RT_Completed`.

I can match one but I don't know how to match both.  I tried:

```
select RTTech.First_Name as RT_First_Name,
       RTTech.Last_Name as RT_Last_Name
from Technician as RTTech 
         Join RT_Queue_Delta as RT 
         on RT.RT_Completed = RTTech.Tech_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to the `Technician` table multiple times:

```
select d.tech_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, 
       d.rt_completed as completed_id, 
       t2.first_name as completed_first_name, 
       t2.last_name as completed_last_name
from RT_QUEUE_Delta d
    join Technician t on d.tech_id = t.tech_id
    join Technician t2 on d.RT_Completed = t2.tech_id
```

Comment: That does exactly what i needed, Thanks a bunch!